# Download image file from the HTML page source

Tags: python, screen-scraping

I am writing a scraper that downloads all the image files from a HTML page and saves them to a specific folder. All the images are part of the HTML page.

Comment: "How can I %s" % title

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Here is some code to download all the images from the supplied URL, and save them in the specified output folder. You can modify it to your own needs.

```
"""
dumpimages.py
    Downloads all the images on the supplied URL, and saves them to the
    specified output file ("/test/" by default)

Usage:
    python dumpimages.py http://example.com/ [output]
"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from urllib.request import (
    urlopen, urlparse, urlunparse, urlretrieve)
import os
import sys

def main(url, out_folder="/test/"):
    """Downloads all the images at 'url' to /test/"""
    soup = bs(urlopen(url))
    parsed = list(urlparse(url))

    for image in soup.findAll("img"):
        print("Image: %(src)s" % image)
        filename = image["src"].split("/")[-1]
        parsed[2] = image["src"]
        outpath = os.path.join(out_folder, filename)
        if image["src"].lower().startswith("http"):
            urlretrieve(image["src"], outpath)
        else:
            urlretrieve(urlunparse(parsed), outpath)

def _usage():
    print("usage: python dumpimages.py http://example.com [outpath]")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = sys.argv[-1]
    out_folder = "/test/"
    if not url.lower().startswith("http"):
        out_folder = sys.argv[-1]
        url = sys.argv[-2]
        if not url.lower().startswith("http"):
            _usage()
            sys.exit(-1)
    main(url, out_folder)
```

**Edit:** You can specify the output folder now.

Comment: `open(..).write(urlopen(..)` could be replaced by `urllib.urlretrieve()`

Comment: Your code fails if image locations are specified relative to the HTML document. Can you please include the [fix provided by unutbu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660419/script-doesnt-download-large-images#answer-8661004) in case someone uses your script in the future?

Comment: @NiklasB. I encountered the same problem. I ended up just using regexp to find all images links, which is more reliable than Beautifulsoup in my opinion.

Answer (score 13):

Ryan's solution is good, but fails if the image source URLs are absolute URLs or anything that doesn't give a good result when simply concatenated to the main page URL.  urljoin recognizes absolute vs. relative URLs, so replace the loop in the middle with:

```
for image in soup.findAll("img"):
    print "Image: %(src)s" % image
    image_url = urlparse.urljoin(url, image['src'])
    filename = image["src"].split("/")[-1]
    outpath = os.path.join(out_folder, filename)
    urlretrieve(image_url, outpath)
```

Answer (score 8):

You have to download the page and parse html document, find your image with regex and download it.. You can use urllib2 for downloading and Beautiful Soup for parsing html file.

Answer (score 8):

And this is function for download one image:

```
def download_photo(self, img_url, filename):
    file_path = "%s%s" % (DOWNLOADED_IMAGE_PATH, filename)
    downloaded_image = file(file_path, "wb")

    image_on_web = urllib.urlopen(img_url)
    while True:
        buf = image_on_web.read(65536)
        if len(buf) == 0:
            break
        downloaded_image.write(buf)
    downloaded_image.close()
    image_on_web.close()

    return file_path
```

Comment: works fine for me when removing the `while` loop (not its content!)

Answer (score 3):

Use htmllib to extract all img tags (override do_img), then use urllib2 to download all the images.

Comment: This assumes non-broken html, which Beautiful Soup can cope with.

Comment: On the other hand, this is using only standard library modules.

Answer (score 1):

If the request need an authorization refer to this one:

```
r_img = requests.get(img_url, auth=(username, password)) 
f = open('000000.jpg','wb') 
f.write(r_img.content) 
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Based on [code here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62207356/1207193)

Removing some lines of code, you'll get only the images `img` tags.

Uses Python 3+ *[Requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/)*, *[BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#)* and other standard libraries.

```
import os, sys
import requests
from urllib import parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
```

```
def savePageImages(url, imagespath='images'):
    def soupfindnSave(pagefolder, tag2find='img', inner='src'):
        if not os.path.exists(pagefolder): # create only once
            os.mkdir(pagefolder)
        for res in soup.findAll(tag2find):  
            if res.has_attr(inner): # check inner tag (file object) MUST exists
                try:
                    filename, ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(res[inner])) # get name and extension
                    filename = re.sub('\W+', '', filename) + ext # clean special chars from name
                    fileurl = parse.urljoin(url, res.get(inner))
                    filepath = os.path.join(pagefolder, filename)
                    if not os.path.isfile(filepath): # was not downloaded
                        with open(filepath, 'wb') as file:
                            filebin = session.get(fileurl)
                            file.write(filebin.content)
                except Exception as exc:
                    print(exc, file=sys.stderr)   
    session = requests.Session()
    #... whatever other requests config you need here
    response = session.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    soupfindnSave(imagespath, 'img', 'src')
```

Use like this bellow to save the `google.com` page images in a folder `google_images`:

```
savePageImages('https://www.google.com', 'google_images')
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import urllib.request as req

with req.urlopen(image_link) as d, open(image_location, "wb") as image_object:
    data = d.read()
    image_object.write(data)
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32483828)