# How to read an entire web page into a variable

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib2

I am trying to read an entire web page and assign it to a variable, but am having trouble doing that. The variable seems to only be able to hold the first 512 or so lines of the page source.

I tried using readlines() to just print all lines of the source to the screen, and that gave me the source in its entirety, but I need to be able to parse it with regex, so I need to store it in a variable somehow. Help?

```
 data = urllib2.urlopen(url)
 print data
```

Only gives me about 1/3 of the source.

```
 data = urllib2.urlopen(url)
 for lines in data.readlines()
      print lines
```

This gives me the entire source.

Like I said, I need to be able to parse the string with regex, but the part I need isn't in the first 1/3 I'm able to store in my variable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download html page and its content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825438/download-html-page-and-its-content)

Answer (score 5):

You probably are looking for beautiful soup: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/   It's an open source web parsing library for python.   Best of luck!

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use [file.read()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects) to read the entire file into a string.  That will give you the entire source.  Something like

```
data = urllib2.urlopen(url)
print data.read()
```

should give you the entire webpage.

From there, don't parse HTML with regex (well-worn post to this effect [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/960195)), but use a dedicated HTML parser instead.  Alternatively, clean up the HTML and convert it to XHTML (for instance with HTML Tidy), and then use an XML parsing library like the standard [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).  Which approach is best depends on your application.

Comment: This doesn't give me any more of the webpage than my first example.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `print data` should not give you any html content because its just a file pointer. Official documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html:

> This function returns a file-like object

This is what I got :

```
print data
<addinfourl at 140131449328200 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x7f72e547fc50>>
```

`readlines()` returns list of lines of html source and you can store it in a string like :

```
import urllib2
data = urllib2.urlopen(url)
l = []
s = ''
for line in data.readlines():
    l.append(line)
s = '\n'.join(l)
```

You can either use list `l` or string `s`, according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend to use opensource web parsing libraries for easy work rather than using regex for complete HTML parsing, any way u need regex for url parsing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse over the variable afterwards you might use [gazpacho](https://github.com/maxhumber/gazpacho):

```py
from gazpacho import Soup

url = "https://www.example.com"
soup = Soup.get(url)
str(soup)
```

That way you can perform `find`s to extract the information you're after!