# Get all tags except a list of tags BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have to extract text from a website with the text boundary i.e. enclosed within a tag.

I wanna filter out all unwanted tags such as

```
'style', 'script', 'head', 'title', 'meta', '[document]'
```

and get the text from the rest of the tags

For Example:

**HTML**

```
<script>console.log('hello');</script>
<span>Header</span>
<p>Some paragraph</p>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['Header', 'Some paragraph']
```

I know I could do

```
soup.findall('span', text=True)
```

and so on for `p` and other tags which contain text

*This is not efficient and thus I need an alternative to filter out all the unwanted elements and then get the text.*

Comment: have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31205497/how-can-i-download-full-webpage-by-a-python-program/31220935#31220935) question thread?

Comment: @debuggingXD This is good, but it doesn't address my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can firstly remove all the unwanted tags from you soup object, like this:

**CODE:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = """<script>console.log('hello');</script>
<span>Header</span>
<p>Some paragraph</p>
"""
tags = ['style', 'script', 'head', 'title', 'meta', '[document]']
soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')

for t in tags:
    [s.extract() for s in soup(t)]

for el in soup.find_all():
    print(el.text)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Header
Some paragraph
```

Then you can see the `script` tags has disapears and you can work on the soup object as you want

Comment: I'm not able to understand this. Could you explain more?

Comment: @Vishnudev of course! `extract` is a method wich allow you to extract string or element from the soup element. See here: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract   Here in my snippet it read in the `tags` list and extract all the element you listed inside (only one `script` in this case) and update your initial soup element. So you just have finally `<span>Header</span>
<p>Some paragraph</p>`

Comment: There's a problem with this. I'll get duplicate text as it iterates through every element because of nesting tags.

Comment: this works. Rather than iterating using find_all I need text directly to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

If you use recent version of BeautifulSoup (I use `beautifulsoup4==4.7.1`), you can use CSS `:not` selector ([doc](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp)):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''
<script>console.log('hello');</script>
<span>Header</span>
<document>This is document</document>
<p>Some paragraph</p>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

l = [tag.text for tag in soup.body.select(':not(style, script, head, title, meta, document)')]
print(l)
```

Prints:

```
['Header', 'Some paragraph']
```

Comment: There's a problem with this. I'll get duplicate text as it iterates through every element because of nesting tags.

Comment: @Vishnudev can you provide the URL or HTML code of your page?

Comment: No. It should be generic. I have 250 urls.