# Python Requests-HTML() unable to load css

Tags: python, css, python-requests, python-requests-html

I'd like to download the css of a page and achieve the same appearance as in the browser. The problem is that the scraped result looks different.

For example, I want to download the landing page of google.

That's the code I have used:

```py
import requests
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()

r = session.get('https://www.google.com')

r.html.render()

file = open("start.html", "w")
file.write(r.text)
file.close()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I download full webpage by a Python program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31205497/how-can-i-download-full-webpage-by-a-python-program)

Answer (score 0):

The css is usually in a  tag.

Try to parse the page in bs4

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()

r = session.get('https://www.google.com')

r.html.render()

soup=BS(r.text)

css = [link.get("href") for link in soup.findAll("link") if "stylesheet" in link.get("rel")]
```

Now css should be a list of links to the css used