# How to download interactive map from website with Python?

Tags: python

I've been using the code in eusoubrasileiro's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31205497/how-download-a-full-webpage-with-a-python-script/57483456#57483456?newreg=104ea6f67641485a8260d9dd5cb4eb7d) to download webpages with Python.

This doesn't seem to download interactive maps, such as the one found on this [nyt](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2020/us/coronavirus-us-cases.html) page.

Is it possible to download interactive maps such as the one referenced on the NYT page above using Python?  If so, what do I need to look at adding to my code in order to do so? Is there a term other than "interactive map" that I might have luck searching for to learn more about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Interactivity on the we is mostly powered by JavaScript. It would also call out to other web resources, API's etc. You might be able to download that and run it in your browser but it sounds like a lot of work, and you'll never get it truly offline.

Your best bet is most likely to reverse engineer it, figure out where the data is coming from and if you can get access to it, build the interactive part yourself.

Comment: Thanks. Does this remain true even if I don't want to actually interact with the data at all? I just want to get an image of what the graphic looks like when the web page loads. My other option is to just screenshot it each day, but I was hoping to use Python instead.