# Python dryscrape scrape page with cookies

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I wanna get some data from site, which requires loggin in.
I log in by **requests**

```
url = "http://example.com"
response = requests.get(url, {"email":"a@gmail.com", "password":"12345"})
cookies = response.cookies
```

Then I wanna get data from some JS page. Through **requests** it isn't possible, so I have to use **dryscrape** for this.

```
import dryscrape
url = "http://example.com/js-page"
sess = dryscrape.Session()
sess.visit(url)
```

Is it possible to pass cookies to **visit()** or I have to look for another solution?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: if you are trying to load a webpage (works same for .js or .html) then you can use the solution from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825438/download-html-page-and-its-content

Comment: Wait, do you mean you want to get the content after it has been modified by javascript?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I need to access a page with JS, which requires login/password. So I log in with ```requests``` and I want to save cookies and pass them to ```dryscrape```.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not login by dryscrape?

```
session = dryscrape.Session()
session.visit('<url_where_is_login_form>')
name = session.at_xpath('//*[@name="username"]') # Where <input name="username">
name.set("<login>")
password = session.at_xpath('//*[@name="password"]') # Where <input name="password">
password.set("<password>")
# Push the button
name.form().submit()
session.visit("<url to visit with proper cookies>")
```