# How to download an HTML file completely?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I wanna download [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20201217054355/https://twitter.com/FRANKCUNHAIII/status/1339445856811016192) as an HTML, alongside CSS, JavaScript, fonts, etc. How can I do this?

I tried with BS4 as outlined in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825438/download-html-page-and-its-contents/62207356#62207356), but the output HTML didn't look good.

```
import os, sys
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

def savePage(url, pagepath='page'):
    def soupfindnSave(pagefolder, tag2find='img', inner='src'):
        """saves on specified `pagefolder` all tag2find objects"""
        if not os.path.exists(pagefolder): # create only once
            os.mkdir(pagefolder)
        for res in soup.findAll(tag2find):   # images, css, etc..
            try:         
                if not res.has_attr(inner): # check if inner tag (file object) exists
                    continue # may or may not exist
                filename = re.sub('\W+', '', os.path.basename(res[inner])) # clean special chars
                fileurl = urljoin(url, res.get(inner))
                filepath = os.path.join(pagefolder, filename)
                # rename html ref so can move html and folder of files anywhere
                res[inner] = os.path.join(os.path.basename(pagefolder), filename)
                if not os.path.isfile(filepath): # was not downloaded
                    with open(filepath, 'wb') as file:
                        filebin = session.get(fileurl)
                        file.write(filebin.content)
            except Exception as exc:
                print(exc, file=sys.stderr)
        return soup
    
    session = requests.Session()
    #... whatever other requests config you need here
    response = session.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, features="lxml")
    pagepath, _ = os.path.splitext(pagepath) # avoid duplicate .html
    pagefolder = pagepath+'_files' # page contents
    soup = soupfindnSave(pagefolder, 'img', 'src')
    soup = soupfindnSave(pagefolder, 'link', 'href')
    soup = soupfindnSave(pagefolder, 'script', 'src')
    with open(pagepath+'.html', 'wb') as file:
        file.write(soup.prettify('utf-8'))
    return soup

soup = savePage('https://web.archive.org/web/20201217054355/https://twitter.com/FRANKCUNHAIII/status/1339445856811016192', 'google')
```

Comment: `the output HTML didn't look good`: Obviously after downloading resources you will also have to rewrite references to them with your static links. It's not _that_ trivial.

Comment: But [wayback_machine_downloader](https://github.com/hartator/wayback-machine-downloader) does this perfectly, so what makes Python inferior to Ruby when it comes to downloading HTML pages?

Comment: Well, that project is approximately 1,000 lines of Ruby code. If you port the code from Ruby to Python writing a comparable number of lines, I'm sure it will also work perfectly. Your ~50 line prototype just doesn't cut it.