# Batch downloading text and images from URL with Python / urllib / beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2, urllib

I have been browsing through several posts here but I just cannot get my head around batch-downloading images and text from a given URL with Python.

```
import urllib,urllib2
import urlparse
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import os, sys

def getAllImages(url):
    query = urllib2.Request(url)
    user_agent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 1.0.3705)"
    query.add_header("User-Agent", user_agent)

    page = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(query))
    for div in page.findAll("div", {"class": "thumbnail"}):
        print "found thumbnail"
        for img in div.findAll("img"):
            print "found image"
            src = img["src"]
            if src:
                src = absolutize(src, pageurl)
                f = open(src,'wb')
                f.write(urllib.urlopen(src).read())
                f.close()
        for h5 in div.findAll("h5"):
            print "found Headline"
            value = (h5.contents[0])
            print >> headlines.txt, value


def main():
    getAllImages("http://www.nytimes.com/")
```

Above is now some updated code. What happens, is nothing. The code does not get to find any div with a thumbnail, obviously, no result in any of the print.... So probably I am missing some pointers in getting to the right divs containing the images and headlines?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You might get more detailed answers if you could explain what exact issues you are running into when you try to download the file. Have you read posts like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042757/downloading-a-picture-via-urllib-and-python, which contain code for downloading images in their answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OS you are using doesn't know how to write to the file path you are passing it in `src`.  Make sure that the name you use to save the file to disk is one the OS can actually use:

```
src = "abc.com/alpha/beta/charlie.jpg"
with open(src, "wb") as f:
    # IOError - cannot open file abc.com/alpha/beta/charlie.jpg

src = "alpha/beta/charlie.jpg"
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(src))
with open(src, "wb" as f:
    # Golden - write file here
```

and everything will start working.

A couple of additional thoughts:

1. Make sure to normalize the save file path (e. g. `os.path.join(some_root_dir, *relative_file_path*)`) - otherwise you'll be writing images all over your hard drive depending on their `src`.
2. Unless you are running tests of some kind, it's good to advertise that you are a bot in your `user_agent` string and honor `robots.txt` files (or alternately, provide some kind of contact information so people can ask you to stop if they need to).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply, unfortunately, after having changed that one line, still I get no result in any way. Running the code just results in nothing.... :(

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 40, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 35, in main
    call = getAllImages("http://www.nytimes.com/")
  File "test.py", line 21, in getAllImages
    f = open(src,'wb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'http://i1.nyt.com/images/2011/10/27/us/cain1/cain1-thumbStandard.jpg'     ..... is this the point where the normalizing of the part comes into play!?

Comment: @user1016690 - yes, that is what I was talking about.  You're trying to open a file on your hard drive at `http://i1.nyt.com/images/2011/10/27/us/cain1/cain1-thumbStandard.jpg` ... and the OS legitimately complains that there is not a writable device called `http://`. :-)

Comment: BeautifulSoup4 hadles file-like objects just fine. Just sayin'.

Comment: @Martijn - *chuckles* yes, indeed it does.  Updated to address the actual cause of the problem. Thanks for helping make the answer better!