# web scraping - how to download image into a folder python

Tags: python, image, beautifulsoup

I have this code where i would like to download the image and save it into a folder but i am getting the src of the image.I have gone through stack overflow where i found this [Batch downloading text and images from URL with Python / urllib / beautifulsoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918239/batch-downloading-text-and-images-from-url-with-python-urllib-beautifulsoup) but have no idea how to proceed

Here is my code,so far i have tried

```
elm5=soup.find('div', id="dv-dp-left-content")
img=elm5.find("img")
src = img["src"]
print src
```

How can i download these images using url into a folder

Comment: Did you read the source code in the *question*? The `<img>` tag is *just a pointer*, the `src` attribute tells your browser where to load the image. It is not included directly in the HTML itself.

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497840/beautifulsoup-how-to-open-images-and-download-them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT: 2021.07.19**

Updated from `urllib` (Python 2) to `urllib.request` (Python 3)

---

```
import urllib.request

f = open('local_file_name','wb')
f.write(urllib.request.urlopen(src).read())
f.close()
```

`src` have to be full path - for example`http://hostname.com/folder1/folder2/filename.ext`.

If `src` is `/folder1/folder2/filename.ext` you have to add `http://hostname.com/`.
If `src` is `folder2/filename.ext` you have to add `http://hostname.com/folder1/`.
etc.

---

**EDIT:** example how to download `StackOverflow` logo :)

```
import urllib.request

f = open('stackoverflow.png','wb')
f.write(urllib.request.urlopen('https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/unified/sprites.svg?v=fcc0ea44ba27').read())
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

the `src` attribute contains the image's url.

you can download it with:

`urllib.request.urlretrieve(src, "image.jpg")`