# Django: Download Image from URL, Resize it, append "small" to the end of the filename

Tags: python, django, image

I'm looking for a way to download an 640x640 image from a URL, resize the image to 180x180 and append the word small to the end of the resized image filename.

For example, the image is located at this link 
http://0height.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/18-japanese-food-instagram-1.jpg

Once resized, I would like to append the world small to the end of the filename like so:
18-japanese-food-instagram-1small.jpeg

How can this be done? Also will the downloaded image be saved to memory or will it save to the actual drive? If it does save to the drive, is it possible to delete the original image and keep the resized version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try urllib?

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve("http://0height.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/18-japanese-food-instagram-1.jpg", "18-japanese-food-instagram-1.jpg")
```

Then, to resize this you can use PIL or another library

```
import Image
im1 = Image.open("18-japanese-food-instagram-1.jpg")    
im_small = im1.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
im_small.save("18-japanese-food-instagram-1_small.jpg")
```

References:

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/code/216637/resize-an-image-python
[Downloading a picture via urllib and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042757/downloading-a-picture-via-urllib-and-python)