# Is there a way to resize jpgs via http in python?

Tags: python, http, web-crawler, jpeg

I am writing a webcrawler that finds and saves the urls of all the images on a website. I can get these without problem. I need to upload these urls, along with a thumbnail version of them, to a server via http request, which will render the image and collect feature information to use in various AI applications.

For some urls this works no problem.

http://images.asos-media.com/products/asos-waxed-parka-raincoat-with-zip-detail/7260214-1-khaki

resizes into

http://images.asos-media.com/products/asos-waxed-parka-raincoat-with-zip-detail/7260214-1-khaki?wid=200

but for actual .jpg images this method doesn't work, like for this one:

https://cdn-images.farfetch-contents.com/11/85/29/57/11852957_8811276_480.jpg

How can I resize the jpgs via url?

Comment: You seem to be hoping that the server you are downloading from will automatically resize? This is not a universal feature, so you will have to resize manually. Libraries like OpenCV can do this very easily; if you post your code we might suggest how this could be implemented.

Comment: The server has to have been designed to resize the image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: Download Image from URL, Resize it, append "small" to the end of the filename](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18703328/django-download-image-from-url-resize-it-append-small-to-the-end-of-the-fil)

Comment: As a side note, I sure hope `asos-media.com` employs some safety caps because if it doesn't it would be an easy target for DoS either due to processing, bandwidth or storage (as it caches resized images).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resizing the image via the URL only works if the site you're hitting is using a dynamic media service or tool in their stack. That's why ASOS will allow you to append a query with the dimensions for resize, however different DM tools will have different query parameters.

If you want to make it tolerant you're best off downloading the image, resizing it with Python and then uploading it.