# sorl-thumbnail and image download

Tags: django, sorl-thumbnail

I have made a news portal with Django that news add manually in database. I have used [sorl-thumbnail](https://github.com/sorl/sorl-thumbnail) for news images. But the client wants to add news from an external source that received from json.

I have to save image name in database and download image. Could I use sorl-thumbnail in second way? Or I have to change my all upload system?

Comment: If you are receiving the json on the server (via `simplejson` for example), you can take the urls in the json and [download the full image using `urllib`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042757/downloading-a-picture-via-urllib-and-python). You then use sorl on that image to create thumbnails

Answer (score 2):

From [sorl-thumbnail docs](http://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html):

**Using external images and advanced cropping:**

```
{% thumbnail "http://www.aino.se/media/i/logo.png" "40x40" crop="80% top" as im %}  
    <img src="{{ im.url }}">
{% endthumbnail %}
```

It is likely that you will need to do some changes to your models, but as far as sorl-thumbnail goes, it should have no problems with external images.