# Saving Ipython Notebook with html figures as pdf?

Tags: python, pdf, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am using Ipython Notebook and I would like to save the notebook as pdf. When a notebook contains html figures in markdown mode I cannot export them

In example:

```
<img src='http://draftingmanuals.tpub.com/14262/img/14262_140_2.jpg'>
```

represents the following:

[image]

However, when I download the notebook as PDF via LaTeX (pdf) the result is without the figure:

[image]

Is this a bug or can I avoid this somehow?

Comment: From the browser you can print as pdf, You can use http://wkhtmltopdf.org/ from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really a bug, but a known limitation. Actually there are two issues in your example:

1. the raw html `<img>` tag gets stripped when the markdown cells are converted by pandoc to latex (see [pandoc docu](http://pandoc.org/README.html#raw-html)).
2. you link to a remote image, which is (currently) not downloaded prior to the conversion.

Thus, it is a bit tricky to get what you desire. The first issue may be overcome by means of a custom filter and custom template. For the second, you may need a custom preprocessor.

Alternatively, you could use python with urllib (e.g. [Downloading a picture via urllib and python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3042757/2870069)) and matplotlib to display this image. Such embedded images are converted fine.