# Cannot download images with dynamic input python

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib

I am trying to download images with Python and I found some good answers in [Downloading a picture via urllib and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042757/downloading-a-picture-via-urllib-and-python) , but when I try to use easygui to type in a url the image just opens in my browser instead of downloading the image

Here is my code:

```
import easygui as eg
import os
import urllib

url = eg.enterbox('Enter url: ', 'URL Choice')
name = eg.enterbox('Enter name: ', 'Name')

def DownloadImage(URL, name):
    try:
        image = urllib.urlopen(URL)
        if image.headers.maintype == 'image':
            buf = image.read()
            path = os.getcwd() + 'C:\Users\USER\ImageGrabber\Pics'
            file_path = '%s%s' % (path,name+'.jpg')
            downloaded_image = file(file_path, 'wb')
            downloaded_image.write(buf)
            image.close()
        else:
            return False
    except:
        print 'Cannot access file'
        return False
    return True

DownloadImage(url,name)
```

I have used the type function and the result from the boxes are strings, so I do not know why it will not work

Edit: forgot to include variables

Comment: I hope you provided the image _type_ to your filename. Simply downloading binary data doesn't help if your computer can't tell if it's in PNG or JPEG format.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error I tried to download this image `https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/775d6701040d31eb0a22479dec666b27?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG` and it seems to work just fine

Comment: @AkshatMahajan yes I have, I just forgot to put that in my post. Another thing I should have mentioned is that the code skips to the except statement every time.

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida I assume you changed the line `path = os.getcwd() + 'C:\Users\USER\ImageGrabber\Pics'` since there is no way that would work on any computer as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Ian When I put a wrong link or a wrong path it does print `Cannot access file`

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida did you put the link in instead of using easygui? When I directly put in the url for the url variable it works fine but when using easygui it skips to the except statement.

Comment: wow I just noticed the catch all `except`, @IanBaker can I suggest removing that or adding `traceback.print_exc()` in it so you can at least see what the error that it gives you?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Thanks to you I found my problem. I was adding a complete file path (starting from C:) when it just needed a file path from where the script was located, which is one up from the Pics folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your target path is wrong `os.getcwd()` gives you the current working directory and you are appending an absolute directory.

So let's say your script is in `C:\myscript.py`, `os.getcwd()` will return `C:\` and you are appending to that `C:\Users\USER\ImageGrabber\Pics`, the result will be `C:\C:\Users\USER\ImageGrabber\Pics` which is an invalid path therefore going to the exception.

```
path='C:\Users\USER\ImageGrabber\Pics\' 
# The last '\' is important
```

that should work

edit

I cannot test because I'm running linux but the directory may need to be like this

```
path='C:/Users/USER/ImageGrabber/Pics/'
```

Comment: I saw @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen 's comment before this, but this was my exact problem, thank you