# Download picture from internet using python

Tags: python, image

I am working on a project, using python, that will take an image[s] from an online webcam such as
[this](https://www.skikelly.com/sf/liveview/?rand=123456789) and then be able to apply some edge detection and motion detection. I have the edge and motion detection running if I import an image already saved on the pi.

I can import an image from the terminal with:

```
wget -nd /pi/Documents/ -A jpg https://www.skikelly.com/sf/liveview/?rand=1234556789
```

I don't know how to put that in a script though.

Comment: Please see this, it is almost what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042757/downloading-a-picture-via-urllib-and-python

Comment: Answer is available here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137817/how-to-download-image-using-requests

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download image using requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137817/how-to-download-image-using-requests)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Downloading a picture via urllib and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042757/downloading-a-picture-via-urllib-and-python)