# How do I loop through a list of dictionaries, grab the image from the URL(value) and write it disk with the key as the file name?

Tags: python

I have a handful of lists of dictionaries that look like this

```
list1 = [{a:b}, {c,d}, {e,f}]
list2 = [{aa:bb}, {cc,dd}, {ee,ff}]
```

The key is an id and the value is a URL. What I am attempting to do is loop though each list of dictionaries and grab the image at the URL(using request or urllib2) and write it to disk using the key as the file name plus some additional identifier. Maybe something like this.

```
5G4d3sweUI89_list1.jpg
```

I'm sure there is an easy solution for this but I'm just not thinking of it. I've jumped into the water before I learned how to swim.

Comment: @Prune Fair enough. Should I delete this question?

Comment: Yes, it's better if you delete it than if we do so.  Start working through tutorials; post *single* problems here when you're well and truly stuck.

Comment: @Prune Can't delete at this point. Won't let me since someone answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the general flow you're going to want to implement:

```
import urllib.request

...

for dicts in list1:                  # iterate over the list of dicts
    for url, filename in dicts.items(): # for each dict, iterate over each key-value pair
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)
```

Basically, just iterate over all of your key-value pairs and then do the thing for all of them. For other ways to download images using python, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45401068).