# facing problem while showing image from server in python

Tags: python, image, url

I am new to python and am trying to show an image from URL using python but I am not able to find any possible solution for this , why my image is not displaying , here is my code

```
image = Image.open("https://images.news18.com/ibnlive/uploads/2019/03/nirav-modi.jpg")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
```

Comment: Where did you get that "Image" module from? Is it pillow?

Comment: yes from PIL import Image, ImageTk

Comment: You need to do the internetz: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042757/downloading-a-picture-via-urllib-and-python