# I downloaded image with urllib.request.urlretrieve and the image is downloaded but it does not open

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I downloaded an image using python urllib library and the image is downloaded but when I try to open it it says "we dont support this extension" in default image software even though I downloaded image as png. I tried this on multiple url but the result is always the same.

```
import urllib.request

def download_image(url):

    full_name = "img3.png"
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_name)


download_image("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Google.png")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Downloading a picture via urllib and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042757/downloading-a-picture-via-urllib-and-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not working because you are not pointing to an image. You are trying to download an html page as a png. Change the url to a png and it will work.

```
import urllib.request

def download_image(url):

    full_name = "img3.png"
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_name)


download_image("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/51/Google.png/800px-Google.png")
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing the mistake but I dont know how to do that. I copied the url of an image

Comment: Thanks. Turns out it was my mistake even though I copied the image url from the web page I had to copy that image url again.

Comment: @MuhammadAhmed Glad you figure it out. If this answer solved your problem, [mark it as answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).