# How to download images from a txt file?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request, wikipedia

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I want to download the images from a Wikipedia page so I write this program, the txt file it's saving with all of the links but I don't know how to continue the program to download files.
Can someone help me?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get 
import urllib.request
import wikipedia
import requests
import re

title = input("Title: ")
link = (wikipedia.page(title).url)
html = urlopen(link)
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
images = bs.find_all('img', {'src':re.compile('.jpg')})
f= open("cache.txt","w+")
for image in images: 
    url = ('https:' + image['src']+'\n')
    f.write(url)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Downloading a picture via urllib and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042757/downloading-a-picture-via-urllib-and-python)

Comment: `import urllib.request;urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)` that is all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it this is the code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get 
import urllib.request
import wikipedia
import requests
import re

title = input("Title: ")
link = (wikipedia.page(title).url)
html = urlopen(link)
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
images = bs.find_all('img', {'src':re.compile('.jpg')})
f= open("cache.txt","w+")
for image in images: 
    url = ('https:' + image['src']+'\n')
    f.write(url)

with open('cache.txt') as f:
   for line in f:
      url = line
      path = 'image'+url.split('/', -1)[-1]
      urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, path.rstrip('\n'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the wget module to download file.

```
pip install wget
```

To download a file using wget

```
wget.download(url)
```

You have to go through each line on your txt file and download the file using wget.

python code

```
import wget
import csv


with open("cache.txt","r") as f:
    line = csv.reader(f)
    for i in line:
        wget.download(i[0])
```

Comment: It appear: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: Check your txt file if the URLs are saving properly. It would be better if you can share a screenshot of your csv file.

Comment: I put a screenshot in the post

Comment: wget.download(i[0]) will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

[image][image]Ifound this maybe help...
It downloads a image but the rest
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

```
import wget
import csv
with open('cache.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
     for row in spamreader:
         wget.download(', '.join(row))
```