# Download an image from a https URL using python

Tags: python, image, url, download, wget

I have a lot of URLs which I need to download and save the image file as a local file.
When I use my browser I can download the Image but in my code I get a ConnectionError.

The problem is when I use a URL of an Image from the web my code works correctly:

```
import wget
import requests
local_file = open('local_file.png','wb')
url = "https://ws.addons.om.prod/subom/mg/prod/contracts/contracts1082/C17510266/401032029940E66_photo_type_identity_front_1613034513765.jpg"
resp = requests.get(url, stream=True,verify=True ,timeout=60)
local_file.write(resp.content)
local_file.close()
```

Comment: That URL gives me - *This site can't be reached.*

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your link is accurate and does not have any errors, which seems to be the issue. You can shorten your code by doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042757/downloading-a-picture-via-urllib-and-python):

```
import requests
f = open('00000001.jpg','wb')
f.write(requests.get('http://www.gunnerkrigg.com//comics/00000001.jpg').content)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have many urls, you need to look for threads(i.e ThreadPoolExecutor) so can download them concurrently.
flow would be:

1. get your URLs in a list say `images_on_a_page`
2. create a function that will download the images, for example:

```
def download_image(img_url):
    data_folder=folder_where_need_to_save_images
    try:
        res=requests.get(img_url,allow_redirects = True,headers=headers)
        img_bytes= requests.get(img_url).content # download bytes for a image
        with open(os.path.join(data_folder,img_name),"wb") as img_file:
            img_file.write(img_bytes)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

3. put the list and function in a `ThreadPoolExecutor`

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(download_image,images_on_a_page)
```

I did something like this for downloading images from flicker. try the [complete program](https://github.com/sandeep1dimri/Programs/blob/master/www.flickr.com.ipynb) , execution step 1 to 7(on notebook).

Comment: Thanks you very much, it's work perfectly

Comment: you are welcome, pls accept the response as an answer :)