# How can I download files form web pages?

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

Some web pages, having their urls, have "Download" Text, which are hyperlinks.

How can I get the hyperlinks form the urls/pages by python or ironpython.

And can I download the files with these hyperlinks by python or ironpython?
How can I do that?

Are there any C# tools?

I am not native english speaker, so sorry for my english.

Comment: @jcao219:Yeas, so sorry, ^_^.

Comment: For the second part of your question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257409/download-image-file-from-the-html-page-source-using-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the [BeautifulSoup library](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) with CPython (normal Python) and IronPython. Check out the [findAll()](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html) method. This should pull out a list of all the links.

```
soup.findAll('a')
```

Comment: Beautiful Soup 中文文档 http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.zh.html

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to pass the HTML page into an XML/HTML parser, and then call `getElementsByTagName("A")` on the root node.  Once you get that, iterate through the list and pull out the `href` parameter.