# Script doesn't download large images

Tags: python

i use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257409/download-image-file-from-the-html-page-source-using-python) script to download images from the same html page. But if images large enough, this script doesnt download properly - all images are 1,15 Kb and dont display.
How can i fix it? what's wrong?

Comment: Can you post an example page where the problem occurs?

Comment: How about an example URL that the script fails on?

Comment: http://tema.ru/travel/new-york.2011.11/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you download and inspect the HTML in http://tema.ru/travel/new-york.2011.11/, you see things like

```
<img src="IMG_5072.jpg" alt="" width="1000" height="667" border="1" />
```

So this page is using relative links.

The line

```
parsed[2] = image["src"]
```

changes `parsed` from

```
['http', 'tema.ru', '/travel/new-york.2011.11/', '', '', '']
```

to

```
['http', 'tema.ru', 'IMG_5072.jpg', '', '', '']
```

and then forms the new url with

```
url = urlparse.urlunparse(parsed)
```

which sets `url` to `http://tema.ru/IMG_5072.jpg` which does not exist.
The correct url is `http://tema.ru/travel/new-york.2011.11/IMG_5072.jpg`.

We can form that url with

```
url = urlparse.urljoin(base_url,image['src'])
```

so try

```
"""
http://stackoverflow.com/a/258511/190597
Author: Ryan Ginstrom
dumpimages.py
    Downloads all the images on the supplied URL, and saves them to the
    specified output file ("/tmp" by default)

Usage:
    python dumpimages.py http://example.com/ [output]
"""
import os
import sys
import urllib
import urllib2
import urlparse
import argparse
import BeautifulSoup

def main(base_url, out_folder):
    """Downloads all the images at 'url' to out_folder"""
    soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(base_url))
    for image in soup.findAll("img"):
        src = image['src']
        print "Image: {s}".format(s=src) 
        _, filename = os.path.split(urlparse.urlsplit(src).path)
        outpath = os.path.join(out_folder, filename)
        url = urlparse.urljoin(base_url, src)
        urllib.urlretrieve(url, outpath)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('url')
    parser.add_argument('out_folder', nargs = '?', default = '/tmp')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(args.url, args.out_folder)
```

Comment: You can leave out the branch in `main` altogether. `urljoin("http://example.org/test.png", "http://google.com/test.png") == "http://google.com/test.png"`

Comment: i copied and pasted your code. it didnt work! IOError [errno 2] no such file or directory: u' /tmp\\arr.gif'

Comment: Change `default = '/tmp'` to a reasonable value for your Windows machine. Set it to some directory used to save downloads. Or, you can run the script with the download folder supplied as an additional argument: `python dumpimages.py http://tema.ru/travel/new-york.2011.11/ C:\\path\to\download\folder`

Comment: @unutbu i tried python dumpimages.py http://tema.ru/travel/new-york.2011.11/ C:\\t  It outputs - unrecognised arguments: C:\\t

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `python dumpimages.py http://tema.ru/travel/new-york.2011.11/ --out C:\\t`.

Comment: @unutbu it still doesnt work!! it outputs  IOError [errno 2] no such file or directory: u'C:\\\\t\\arr.gif'

Comment: Okay, one more try: `python dumpimages.py http://tema.ru/travel/new-york.2011.11/ --out C:\t`.

Comment: @unutbu Still,no luck :(( now it's   IOError [errno 2] no such file or directory: u'C:\\t\\arr.gif'

Comment: Okay, I clearly have no clue how to operate in a Windows environment. What is the path to the desired directory? Do you have a directory named `t` at the top level of the `C:` drive?

Comment: @unutbu Thanks!! i manually created t folder as C:\t and it worked!!:)) I thought it created t folder if that folder didn't exist :(

Comment: Oh, wonderful. Yay! Now that the main problem is solved, I've changed the argparser so `python dumpimages.py http://tema.ru/travel/new-york.2011.11/ C:\t` should work (without the `--out`).

Comment: I am getting invalid syntax for : `print "Image {s}".format(s=src)` at the second quote. Any ideas?

Comment: oops forgot I upgraded to python 3