# Python - How do you run a .py file?

Tags: python, windows, image, download

I've looked all around Google and its archives. There are several good articles, but none seem to help me out. So I thought I'd come here for a more specific answer.

The Objective: I want to run [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257409/download-image-file-from-the-html-page-source-using-python) on a website to get all the picture files at once. It'll save a lot of pointing and clicking.

I've got Python 2.3.5 on a Windows 7 x64 machine. It's installed in C:\Python23.

How do I get this script to "go", so to speak?

**=====================================**

Seeing as how this is top result on Google, here's a useful link I found over the years:

http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex1.html

For setup, see exercise 0.

**=====================================**

As requested, here's the code I'm using:

```
"""
dumpimages.py
Downloads all the images on the supplied URL, and saves them to the
specified output file ("/test/" by default)

Usage:
    python dumpimages.py http://example.com/ [output]
"""

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urlparse
from urllib2 import urlopen
from urllib import urlretrieve
import os
import sys

def main(url, out_folder="C:\asdf\"):
    """Downloads all the images at 'url' to /test/"""
    soup = bs(urlopen(url))
    parsed = list(urlparse.urlparse(url))

    for image in soup.findAll("img"):
        print "Image: %(src)s" % image
        filename = image["src"].split("/")[-1]
        parsed[2] = image["src"]
        outpath = os.path.join(out_folder, filename)
        if image["src"].lower().startswith("http"):
            urlretrieve(image["src"], outpath)
        else:
            urlretrieve(urlparse.urlunparse(parsed), outpath)

def _usage():
    print "usage: python dumpimages.py http://example.com [outpath]"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = sys.argv[-1]
    out_folder = "/test/"
    if not url.lower().startswith("http"):
        out_folder = sys.argv[-1]
        url = sys.argv[-2]
        if not url.lower().startswith("http"):
            _usage()
            sys.exit(-1)
    main(url, out_folder)
```

Comment: Start with the Python Tutorial: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/interpreter.html

Answer (score 23, accepted):

On windows platform, you have 2 choices:

1. In a command line terminal, type

   c:\python23\python xxxx.py
2. Open the python editor IDLE from the menu, and open xxxx.py, then press F5 to run it.

For your posted code, the error is at this line:

```
def main(url, out_folder="C:\asdf\"):
```

It should be:

```
def main(url, out_folder="C:\\asdf\\"):
```

Comment: I tried the first one, received the following error message:
C:\python23\python: can't open file 'dumpImages.py'

Then I realized my mistake:

C:\python23\"python dumpImages.py"

Then I received a syntax error:

EOL while scanning single-quoted string.

What the heck does that mean? Thanks!

Comment: It seems your .py file has wrong format. Please post your code.

Comment: When I run my helloworld file by option 2 , it works.
but when I run another .py file it just shows me the source code.. How to actually make it run ?

Answer (score 5):

Usually you can double click the `.py` file in Windows explorer to run it. If this doesn't work, you can create a batch file in the same directory with the following contents:

```
C:\python23\python YOURSCRIPTNAME.py
```

Then double click that batch file. Or, you can simply run that line in the command prompt while your working directory is the location of your script.

Comment: Double-clicking on a `.py` file on Windows will only run it if it's on the System Path.

Answer (score 4):

Since you seem to be on windows you can do this so `python <filename.py>`. Check that python's bin folder is in your PATH, or you can do `c:\python23\bin\python <filename.py>`. Python is an interpretive language and so you need the interpretor to run your file, much like you need java runtime to run a jar file.

Comment: So, from your example above, this should work?

C:\Python23\bin\python\dumpImages.py

Comment: It will be c:\python23\bin\python dumpImages.py. Python.exe is the interpretor and the file name is dumpImages.py

Comment: Alright. I've got it as specified. It appears to run... however it runs extremely quickly and has no results. I did do this in the cmd prompt:

set path=%path%;C:\python23

So now I can access python via cmd.exe.

I guess the problem I have now is it isn't asking for parameters. As far as I can tell, the script takes two parameters: a url and a location on my hdd. Whenever I run ith through the python shell:

dumpImages(http://www.google.com/, C:\asdf\)

I get an invalid syntax error at the semicolon after http.

Answer (score 3):

use IDLE Editor {You may already have it} it has interactive shell for python and it will show you execution and result.

Answer (score 0):

Your command should include the url parameter as stated in the script usage comments.
The main function has 2 parameters, url and out (which is set to a default value)
C:\python23\python "C:\PathToYourScript\SCRIPT.py" http://yoururl.com "C:\OptionalOutput\"

Answer (score -1):

If you want to run .py files in Windows, Try installing Git bash
Then download python(Required Version) from python.org and install in the main c drive folder

For me, its :

"**C:\Python38**"

then open Git Bash and go to the respective folder where your .py file is stored :

For me, its :

File Location : "Downloads"
File Name : Train.py

So i changed my Current working Directory From "C:/User/(username)/" to "C:/User/(username)/Downloads"

then i will run the below command

" **/c/Python38/python Train.py** "

and it will run successfully.

But if it give the below error :

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'

Then Do not panic :

and use this command :

" **/c/Python38/Scripts/pip install sklearn** "

and after it has installed sklearn go back and run the previous command :

" **/c/Python38/python Train.py** "

and it will run successfully.

!!!!HAPPY LEARNING !!!!

Comment: Why do we need gitbash here, python program can be execute on command prompt?

Comment: Thanks for you efforts! But the second half of the answer has nothing to do with the question

Comment: @ShivamSeth I just gave another method apart from command prompt to run .py files. I use anaconda command prompt to run .py files as well as gitbash. both works fine for me

Comment: @SergeyShubin I have posted the 2nd part of my answer to install libraries.Its just for a safe side. If people get any error saying "module not found" they can refer to this method to install libraries through git bash.