# error in a python script to convert Youtube XML timed text into srt

Tags: python, xml, subtitle

it is possible to get XML code of Youtube closed caption in this URL:

```
http://video.google.com/timedtext?hl=en&lang=en&v=VIDEO_ID
```

which VIDEO_ID is youtube video ID. to convert that code into srt file I used this script:

https://gist.github.com/golive/129171

which is a python code. for running python code I used

```
C:\Python27\python youtube2srt.py
```

according to this:

[Python - How do you run a .py file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493086/python-how-do-you-run-a-py-file)

I copied that code into a file named youtube2srt.py. I saved XML codes of that page to a file as youtube_xml.xml.

when I run it I receive this error:

[image]

when I delete two first lines & run it, I get this error:

[image]

I have almost the same problem with this code:

https://gist.github.com/gorlum0/1290835

what's the problem?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first file you try to run, youtube2srt.py, is actually youtube2srt.rb and is a ruby file - not python.

The second probably requires you to install the package BeautifulSoup, which is not included in the standard python library