# Cmd commands from within python script?

Tags: python, scripting, cmd

I just want to enter integrate these two commands from cmd and use them in a python script, but I'm novice in both programming and python.  How I can achieve this?

```
cd C:\
python dumpimages.py http://google.com C:\images\
```

Comment: Incidentally - my telepathic spider-sense is telling me you might be trying to save images from a webpage. Have you considered using [GNU wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) for that?

Comment: I'm just trying to download changing images whose url is hidden.  It's not a lot of pictures on the page, so I found this script.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257409/download-image-file-from-the-html-page-source-using-python.  More than needed, but it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use the `os.subprocess` module.](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html)

Note that `exec()` will also work but it is deprecated in favour of `os.subprocess`.

Further to my comment above, if all you want to do is retrieve images from a webpage, [use GNU `wget` with the `-A` flag:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602153/how-do-i-use-wget-to-download-all-images-into-a-single-folder)

```
wget -r -P /save/location -A jpeg,jpg,bmp,gif,png http://www.domain.com
```

Comment: Oh nice, I shall try this now!  Thanks!

Comment: Note: the `-r` flag is for 'recursive' - probably only need `-p` for `page display prerequisites`. (Consult [`man wget`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget) for more information.)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the `cd C:\` is not necessary, and once that's gone all you seem to be asking for is a way to launch a python script.

Perhaps all you want is to modify saveimage.py so that it has the hard-coded arguments you want?  I don't know what that script is--maybe you can tell us if it's important or you aren't allowed to modify it.

Comment: It's Greg Hewgill's script from here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257409/download-image-file-from-the-html-page-source-using-python

Trying to download images from a hidden url.  There's only one or two pictures on the page, so I'm using this script because it was quick.

Comment: [You would be better off using `wget`.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602153/how-do-i-use-wget-to-download-all-images-into-a-single-folder)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `sys.argv`

Try:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

on top of your saveimage.py.

It should print something like:

```
['C:\saveimage.py', 'http://google.com', 'C:\images\']
```

You see, sys.argv is a list of strings. The first item is the name of the script itself, the others are the parameters.
Since lists are 0-based, you can access the i-th parameter to the script with `sys.argv[i]`

Comment: Thanks, it's on top of the script already.  I'm just trying to combine two scripts into one.