# How to simulate command prompt in Perl and Python

Tags: python, perl, subprocess, wget, command-prompt

I normally use WGET to download an image or two from some web-page, I do something like this from the command prompt: `wget 'webpage-url' -P 'directory to where I wanna save it'`. Now how do I automate it in Perl and Python? That is what command shall enable me to simulate as if I am entering the command at the command-prompt? In Python there are so many similar looking modules like subprocess, os, etc that I am quite confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["wget", "www.example.com", "-P", "/dir/to/save"])
```

If you want to read URL and process the response:

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://example.com/')
html = response.read()
```

How to extract images from the html you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257409/download-image-file-from-the-html-page-source-using-python) on SO

Comment: Thanks! However this process pops up the command prompt window for some time after which it disappears on its own. How to prevent that? There is a definite method, I can't remember!

Comment: I've got little experience on Windows - maybe adding `, shell=true` to the call helps -> `subprocess.call([....], shell=true)`

Comment: Yeah it worked perfectly, although the method I previously used is different. Can you help me out with Perl too?

Comment: Sorry ... I probably can't help you ... No idea about Perl. My font size is changed and this made the "out with Perl" hide behind the ad to the right. I read "Can you help me [linebreak] too?"

Answer (score 8):

In Perl, the easiest way is to use `LWP::Simple`:

```
use LWP::Simple qw(getstore);
getstore('www.example.com', '/path/to/saved/file.ext');
```

Answer (score 2):

in Perl, also, you can use `qx(yourcommandhere)`. this is external call of programs.

so, in your example: `qx(wget 'webpage-url' -P '/home/myWebPages/')`. this is enough for you.

But, as **s0me0ne** said, using `LWP::Simple` is better.

If you have a list of urls in a file, you can use this code:

```
my $fh; # filehandler

open $fh, "<", "fileWithUrls.txt" or die "can't find file with urls!";

my @urls = <$fh>; # read all urls, one in each raw of file

my $wget = '/path/to/wget.exe';    

for my $url(@urls) {
    qx($wget $url '/home/myWebPages/');
}
```