# using images from the web in python

Tags: python, django, image, google-maps, animation

So here is my goal:

Use google maps api to generate a bunch of maps and run them on my computer in real-time similar to what a GIF would look like.

I have a pandas `dataframe` that looks as such:

```
   diffSecs   latitude  longitude  altitude                 time code name
0     1.614  42.386391 -71.013544        50  2011-12-16 08:09:07     PEONY
1     1.115  42.386391 -71.013544        50  2011-12-16 08:09:08     PEONY
2     0.952  42.386391 -71.013544        50  2011-12-16 08:09:09     PEONY
3     0.923  42.386391 -71.013544        50  2011-12-16 08:09:10     PEONY
4     1.307  42.386391 -71.013544        50  2011-12-16 08:09:11     PEONY
```

So I have a function that runs through the latitude and longitude and creates a list consisting of hundreds of urls that are images of a map with a point on the persons position.

here is the function:

```
def url_maker(df):
    urls = []
    df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
    name = df['code name'][0]
    if name == "APPLE" or name == "DAFODIL" or name == "LILLY" or name == "LILY" or name == "ORANGE" or name == "ROSE" or name == "SUNFLOWER" or name == "SWEETPEA":
        label = "C"
        color = 'blue'
    else:
        label = "P"
        color = 'red'
    lats,lons = df.latitude, df.longitude
    center = home_finder(df)
    for i in range(len(df)-1):
        x,y = str(lats[i]),str(lons[i])
        marker = '&markers=color:' + color + '%7Clabel:' + label + '%7C' + x + ',' + y
        url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&zoom=7&center=' + center + marker + '&sensor=true'
        urls.append(url)
    return urls
```

This will return a list of urls that are the persons position on the map. So you know, the `home_finder` function takes gps coordinates in a dataframe and approximates where the person lives so I can watch how far they go from their home.

**So here is my question:**

Now that I have a list of all the image urls I need, How can I make a movie out of it so I can watch the point move in real time? Is there a module that can do this for me? I have been stuck on this for over a week!

**note:**

I had a thought about doing this in Django with a loop to live update the  tag, but I have never used Django before so I really don't know if that is possible, and if it is how I can do that. If I could do it in Django, how would I be able to? **But** if it is possible to do this on my own computer and maybe save it in a GIF or MOV file, that would be 100 times better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each url, use `urllib` and `BeautifulSoup` to download the image at that page ([See this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257409/download-image-file-from-the-html-page-source-using-python)).

Use the `subprocess` module to run an [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) script that will create your MOV of GIF file:

```
convert -quality 100 *.png maps.mov
```

or:

```
convert -set delay 3 -loop 0 -scale 50% *.png maps.gif
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems very promising, I will vote up and check once I test it out! Quickly before I do...now I will have to do this with a hell of a lot of images. Is there a way to temporarily grab the image from the url without downloading it? And if not, will the way you posted take a very long time to download and package into the MOV/GIF file?

Comment: I'll just add a part at the end of the script to delete the pngs of images after it makes the movie. Anyways so I understand this better, at the end of my code I should put the following: `os.system('convert -quality 100 *.png maps.mov')` and it will compile all of the .png files in the current working directory to `maps.mov`. Right?

Comment: Yes that command would be correct assuming it's run from the same directory as all your images saved as PNG files.  However the `subprocess` module is preferred to using `os.system`. Check out the `subprocess` docs page on replacing `os.system` calls:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements

Comment: thanks for pointing that out! And since I create the url of the image I actually don't need the beautiful soup, I can just do `urlretrieve(url, file_name)`. I am downloading ImageMagick now to see if it will work!

Comment: didn't work with a mov file, which is preferred. I'm trying GIF now, but this is the error I get when I try for MOV: `convert: delegate failed "ffmpeg" -v -1 -mbd rd -trellis 2 -cmp 2 -subcmp 2 -g 300 -i "%M%%d.jpg" "%u.%m" 2> "%Z"' @ error/delegate.c/InvokeDelegate/1065.`. I get that error when I download the images both as JPGs and PNGs. Also there is a '`' before "ffmpeg" but it messed up the code format for comments so I took it out

Comment: It works for the gif code you supplied. How can I get it to work with a movie?

Comment: ImageMagick needs FFMpeg installed and set up as a delegate to support that conversion. Run `convert -list configure` from the command line and check the `DELEGATES` line of ouput for `mpeg` to see if it is already setup.

Comment: oh, no it is not. How do I get it to be there?

Comment: Install FFMpeg first if its not already installed. Try a quick Google search for the recommended installation process for your distribution.  Then find ImageMagick's delegates.xml file (should be in the config directory), and add the line `<delegate decode=”ffmpeg” command=’”ffmpeg” -i “%i” -y -vcodec png -ss %s -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo “%o”‘ />`

Comment: I added all of that and saved it and installed ffmpeg and then did the `convert -list configure` and it was not in delegates. this is what i got: `DELEGATES     bzlib fftw fontconfig freetype gs jpeg jng lcms2 lzma png tiff x11 xml zlib`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30788/discussion-between-butch-and-ryan-saxe)