# Download a HTML page locally (+CSS, +images)

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'd like to be able to download a HTML page (let's say this actual question!):

```
f = urllib2.urlopen('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33914277')
content = f.read()       # soup = BeautifulSoup(content) could be useful?
g = open("mypage.html", 'w')
g.write(content)
g.close()
```

such that it is displayed the same way locally than online. Currently here is the (bad) result:

[image]
<sub>(source: [gget.it](http://gget.it/z208ggpf/4.jpg))</sub>

Thus, one need to download CSS, and modify the HTML itself such that it points to this local CSS file... and the same for images, etc.

**How to do this?** (I think there should be simpler than [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257409/download-image-file-from-the-html-page-source-using-python/258511#258511), that doesn't handle CSS, but how? Library?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download image file from the HTML page source using python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257409/download-image-file-from-the-html-page-source-using-python)

Comment: @KDawG : I have linked this question in my own question, haven't you seen? The difficult CSS part is not handled.

Comment: With today's use of javascript it's unreasonable to download everything locally as you cannot know what resources the site has.

Comment: @simonzack that's why I would like to limit the "scraping" to CSS and images. Such that, for example, this [precise page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33914277) could be saved locally.

Comment: @Basj Javascript is able to load any css or image it likes.

Comment: I can't seem to understand your logic here, don't reinvent the wheel, just use the solution that has already been provided.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4200547/408556)

Comment: But my personal favorite is [httrack](https://www.httrack.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Since css and image files fall under [CORS](http://scraping.pro/web-scraping-with-javascript-load-html-page/#cors) policy, from your local html you still can refer to them while they are in the cloud. The problem is unresolved URIs. In the html head section you have smth. like this:

```
    <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/8943fcf6/select.css" />
    <link href="/css/media.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery.yii.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/select.js"></script>
</head>
```

Obviously `/css/media.css` implies base address, ex. `http://example.com`. To resolve it for local file you need to make `http://example.com/css/media.css` as *href* value in your local copy of html. So now you should parse and add the base into the local code:

```
    <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://example.com/assets/select.css" />
    <link href="http://example.com/css/media.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/assets/jquery.yii.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/assets/select.js"></script>
</head>
```

Use any means for that (js, php...)

### Update

Since a local file also contains images' references throughout the *body* section you'll need to resolve them too.