# Is it possible to retrieve a Javascript file from a server?

Tags: javascript, python

In Python, I can retrieve Javascript from an HTML document using the following code.

```
import urllib2, jsbeautifier
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.com.ph/")

soup = BeautifulSoup(f, "lxml")
script_raw = str(soup.script)

script_pretty = jsbeautifier.beautify(script_raw)
print(script_pretty)
```

But how about if the script comes from a Javascript file on the server, like:

```
<script src="some/directory/example.js" type="text/javascript">
```

Is it possible to retrieve "example.js"? If so, how?

Context: I'm examining the Javascript of phishing web pages.

Comment: If the target of `<script src=...>` is not accessible to clients, it won't be executed because Javascript has to run client-side. If you're on `fishysite.net/phishyPath/phishyPage.html` then `some/directory/example.js` will typically be available at some path like `fishysite.net/phishyPath/some/directory/example.js`.

Comment: In urllib use urlretrive here is an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257409/download-image-file-from-the-html-page-source-using-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="some/directory/example.js" type="text/javascript">
```

the code above will get `some/directory/example.js` from server
you just make folders and file structure follow the pattern above

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to right click on that page in your browser, choose `page script`, click on that `.js` link, and it will be there.

Comment: Thanks, this validates Alongkorn's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load at run time, like some part of your javascript is dependent on other javascript, then for loading javascript at run time, you can use require.js .